# X fails to start with five displays multi-desktop fglrx

Tags: xorg, fglrx

Fresh install of 12.04.1 LTS x86-64, Sapphire Flex HD6950 video card.

- I initally booted with one display connected, added the other four, and they all worked (cloned)
- I can set them to "Multi-display desktop" and get five independent displays, but each has its own Unity bars. (I eventually want to merge four of these into a single work area treated as one display)
- In pursuit of Xinerama, I set them to "Single Display Desktop (Multi-desktop)", which requires a restart.  During the subsequent boot, X fails to start.

Interesting bit from the end of /var/log/Xorg.0.log :

```
[    14.517] (II) fglrx(4): [uki] DRM interface version 1.0
[    14.517] (II) fglrx(4): [uki] created "fglrx" driver at busid "PCI:1:0:0"
[    14.517] (II) fglrx(4): [uki] added 8192 byte SAREA at 0x2000
[    14.517] (II) fglrx(4): [uki] mapped SAREA 0x2000 to 0x7fb706a97000
[    14.518] (II) fglrx(4): [uki] framebuffer handle = 0x3000
[    14.518] (II) fglrx(4): [uki] added 1 reserved context for kernel
[    14.518] (II) fglrx(4): swlDriScreenInit done
[    14.518] (EE) fglrx(4): Not enough video memory to allocate primary surface (frame buffer).
[    14.518] (II) fglrx(4): Shutdown CMMQS
[    14.518] (II) fglrx(4): [uki] removed 1 reserved context for kernel
[    14.518] (II) fglrx(4): [uki] unmapping 8192 bytes of SAREA 0x2000 at 0x7fb706a97000
[    14.518] (WW) fglrx(4): ***********************************************************
[    14.518] (WW) fglrx(4): * DRI initialization failed                               *
```

This line in particular drew my attention: `fglrx(4): Not enough video memory to allocate primary surface (frame buffer).`  The card has two gigabytes of memory.

I'm using latest stable driver from AMD (12.8), built .debs with this guide:
[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers)

Somebody else that has had this error worked around it with the "nopat" kernel param; I tried that and it didn't help ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1004546 )

I also messed with ServerLayout in xorg.conf a bit, wondering if 9600 horizontal pixels was too much:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
        Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
        Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[1]-1" 1920 0
        Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[1]-2" 3840 0
        Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[1]-3" 5760 0
        # my failure occurs with either of these lines:
        Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[1]-4" 5760 1200
        # Screen         "amdcccle-Screen[1]-4" 7680 0
EndSection
```

## Update: 3840 Limit?

When I use the Ubuntu Displays configurator instead of AMD's thing, it seems to tell me that there's a hard limit of 3840x3840 for the entire virtual desktop:

```
requested position/size for CRTC 149 is outside the allowed limit: position=(3840,3840), size=(1920, 1200), maximum=(3840,3840)
```

Googling around, I see others encountering the same error with a variety of maximum limits - how is this number derived?  How might I increase it?

As a workaround for now I can rearrange the screens on this dialog to fit inside the 3840x3840 square, but that doesn't reflect the physical layout of my displays.

I don't have enough rep yet on *this* stack exchange site to embed an image, but here's the dialog with the 3840 limit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKAld.png

Comment: To me, 5 displays connected to one card seems a bit too much. Maybe try to connect those monitors using low resolution first. Does it work that way?

Comment: It works under Windows, and is a selling point of this card!  (They call it "Eyefinity")  I don't _actually_ have five displays; I have two - one fairly standard 1920x1200, and one ridiculous 3840x2400 monster that acts as if it were four displays, using four single-link DVI cables.  (IBM T221).  I'm unable to test with lower resolutions because the display won't take them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted AMD support, and I'm happy to report the "Not enough video memory to allocate primary surface (frame buffer)" issue is fixed as of Catalyst 12.11.

Comment: If that’s true, then it reappeared later. I have 15.201 and am facing exactly this issue.